# Get the maximum value using stream for Map

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have a class called Test. This class has a method called getNumber which returns an int value.

```
public class Test{
     .
     .
     .
     .
     public int getNumber(){
          return number;
     }
}
```

Also I have a HashMap which the key is a Long and the value is a Test object.

```
Map<Long, Test> map = new HashMap<Long, Test>();
```

I want to print the key and also getNumber which has a maximum getNumber using a Stream Line code.

I can print the maximum Number via below lines

```
final Comparator<Test> comp = (p1, p2) -> Integer.compare(p1.getNumber(), p2.getNumber());

map.entrySet().stream().map(m -> m.getValue())
     .max(comp).ifPresent(d -> System.out.println(d.getNumber()));
```

However my question is How can I return the key of the maximum amount? Can I do it with one round using stream?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood you correctly:

```
Entry<Long, Test> entry = map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.comparingInt(Test::getNumber)))
            .get();
```

Comment: There is no reason to turn to an expensive `.sorted(…) .findFirst()`. You can still use `max` as in the OP’s code, the only trick is not to do the `map` step: `map.entrySet() .stream() .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.comparingInt(Test::getNumber))) .get()`

Comment: Mind the removal of `Comparator.reverseOrder()`; it was needed when you tried to use `findFirst()` to get the maximum, but isn’t needed when you use `max` in the first place. In my comment, I also used the opportunity to change it to `comparingInt` for the natural order.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find the key-value pair corresponding to the maximum 'number' value in the Test instances, you can use `Collections.max()` combined with a comparator that compares the entries with this criteria.

```
import static java.util.Comparator.comparingInt;

...

Map.Entry<Long, Test> maxEntry = 
    Collections.max(map.entrySet(), comparingInt(e -> e.getValue().getNumber()))
```

If you want to use the stream way, then remove the mapping (because you lost the key associated with the value), and provide the same comparator:

```
map.entrySet()
   .stream()
   .max(comparingInt(e -> e.getValue().getNumber()))
   .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Note that there is a small difference in both snippets, as the first one will throw a `NoSuchElementException` if the provided map is empty.